# How to make http call from logic app which connects to sever via proxy

Tags: azure, http, http-headers, azure-logic-apps

I am newbie to Azure Logicapp. 2-3 months of experience.

In Azure Logic app ISE, I am trying to make http call to customer end via our proxy, but i don't see any option to specify proxy server and port in Http Connector. I read the documentation but could not find any where. Some of the option I tried is to adding below http headers:

```
URL-https://Customerurl.com
{
  "X-Forwarded-Host": "172.16.161.70:5555",   --> Proxy server:port
  "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http"
}
```

But that's not working, don't see any request coming to proxy server, instead its calling directly to customer url.

Seek help here. Any help is appreciated. How to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

While Logic Apps don't have a way to redirect traffic via a proxy, you could [setup VNET Routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview) that forward traffic to your proxy.

This is useful in cases where you would like to ensure all requests come from a single IP Address when working with multiple ISEs and data sources that have IP Restrictions in place. [This official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-set-up-single-ip-address) covers the steps in details.